# SQL count Query retrieving 0

Tags: php, sql

i want to list the amount of views per object_id, between the current date and the date year ago.
So, i have this Query:

```
SELECT count(*) FROM event_logs WHERE object_id=252 AND object_type='product' AND event_type='view' AND event_date BETWEEN 2014-02-14 AND 2015-02-14 GROUP BY month(event_date)
```

And the following table:

```
event_id | user_id | objectd_id | object_type | event_type | event_date
1        | 1       |    252     |   product   | view       | 2014-02-25 00:00:00
2        | 1       |    252     |   product   | view       | 2015-02-12 19:36:05
3        | 1       |    252     |   product   | view       | 2015-01-05 19:36:05
```

The problem is when i execute the query, show an amount of results of 0 (zero),

Could have i been doing wrong?

Please help and thank you all for your attention!

Comment: You group by in your query but according to your question you don't want any grouping. Which one is correct?

Comment: Try quoting the dates `BETWEEN '2014-02-14' AND '2015-02-14'`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change to this

```
BETWEEN '2014-02-14 00:00:00' AND '2015-02-14 23:59:59'
```

Comment: That really depends on what range he's interested in. I doubt this alone is the reason he doesn't get *any* results.

Comment: Yup! Sorry to all but the problem was really due to the time not being establish!
Thank you all

Answer (score 2):

One problem is the `event_date` constants:

```
SELECT count(*)
FROM event_logs
WHERE object_id = 252 AND
      object_type = 'product' AND 
      event_type = 'view' AND
      event_date BETWEEN 2014-02-14 AND 2015-02-14
------------------------^ ---------^---^----------^ missing quotes
GROUP BY month(event_date);
```

Date constants should be in single quotes.  Otherwise, these are treated as arithmetic -- 2014 - 2 - 14 = 1998, which is not really a valid date.

Also, if you want the total value, it is unclear why you are grouping by the month.  You can use `CURRENT_DATE` and date arithmetic and not have to hardcode the dates:

```
SELECT count(*)
FROM event_logs
WHERE object_id = 252 AND
      object_type = 'product' AND 
      event_type = 'view' AND
      event_date <= CURRENT_DATE and
      event_date > date_sub(CURRENT_DATE, interval -1 year);
```

Depending on the exact logic, you might want to change the `<=` to `<` or whatever -- depending on whether you want to include the end dates.  Note:  if `event_date` has a time component, then you might want to use `date(event_date)` to strip it off.

Comment: You didn't put the event_date in constants yourself, I guess to illustrate where it's wrong, but that seems a bit confusing. I would change the BETWEEN to have the dates properly quoted to make it clear that this would be the correct way to write the SQL.